# recursive backtracking for sudoku?

Tags: javascript, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

Im trying to make a sudoku solver algorithm to practice recursion and backtracking, so made this function 'backtrack' which is the main function that's supposed to solve it , and four other 'utility/helper' functions;the first one is 'getSubGrid' which returns the subgrid where the current number belongs,and then 'getColumn' which returns the column where the current number belongs, and 'getRow' which returns the row where the current number belongs, and the last helper function is 'subGridIncludes' to check whether a subgrid includes a specific number or not.The problem is that for some boards, this code works and solve them, but for some other boards it doesn't and it gives me 'too much recursion' error.Note that i tried to calculate how many recursive calls each board requires and i found that the boards that worked required less than 6000 calls , but the one of the boards that didnt work required more than 10000 call before i got the message 'too much recursion',and i want to know if the error is because i didnt set a base case that was present in the boards that were not solved and not present in the boards that were solved, or is it because the board is just big and i need to rewrite the script in a way that requires the least amount of recursive calls.

these are examples of the boards that were succesfully solved:

```
board 1:
[
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]

board 2:
[
    [0,2,0,0,0,8,0,0,4],
    [0,9,0,1,0,0,6,0,0],
    [0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,0],

    [9,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,8],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,2],
    [0,0,5,0,8,3,0,0,7],

    [0,0,4,0,0,0,9,2,0],
    [7,0,0,3,0,0,8,5,0],
    [0,0,0,2,5,6,4,0,3]
]
```

and this is an example of a board that the function didnt solve:

```
[
    [1,0,0, 0,5,0, 0,4,0],
    [0,0,0, 9,0,0, 0,0,1],
    [0,0,0, 0,0,3, 8,0,0],
  
    [0,5,0, 8,0,2, 4,0,0],
    [0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0],
    [4,0,0, 0,0,0, 7,5,3],
      
    [5,0,0, 3,0,0, 0,6,0],
    [0,2,0, 0,0,1, 3,7,0],
    [0,6,0, 4,0,9, 0,0,0]
]
```

and this is the code:

```
let lastPopped; // variable to keep track of the last changed value
let addedVals = [[]]; // array of arrays to keep track of the indexes where the values were changed on each row,where the index of each subarray corresponds to the index of the row


backtrack()


function backtrack(currentRowIndex = 0, currentRow = board[currentRowIndex], testValue = 1, i = 0) {
    // testValue is a value put under test to check if its included in the row, column,subgrid
    if (currentRowIndex === board.length) {
        // this condition checks the board is finished ,if so it stops the execution of the function.
        return
    } else if (i === currentRow.length) {
        // this condition checks if we reached the end of the current row ,if so it takes us to the next row.
        lastPopped = undefined
        addedVals.push(new Array())
        backtrack(currentRowIndex + 1, currentRow = board[currentRowIndex + 1], testValue = 1, i = 0)
    } else if (testValue > 9) {
        // this condition checks if the testValue is greater than 9,if so we know that we should set the current value to 0 and we backtrack to the previous value.
        currentRow[i] = 0
        if (i === 0 || (addedVals[currentRowIndex].length === 0)) {
            // this condition checks whether we are at the start of a row or the previous values are original, if so we backtrack to the previous row.
            lastPopped = addedVals[currentRowIndex - 1].pop()
            backtrack(currentRowIndex - 1, currentRow = board[currentRowIndex - 1], testValue = board[currentRowIndex - 1][lastPopped] + 1, i = lastPopped)
        } else {
            // if the previous condtion is not satisfied we backtrack to the previous value plus one in the same row.
            lastPopped = addedVals[currentRowIndex].pop()
            backtrack(currentRowIndex, currentRow = board[currentRowIndex], testValue = currentRow[lastPopped] + 1, i = lastPopped)
        }

    } else {
        if (currentRow[i] === 0 || i === lastPopped) {
            // this condition checks if the current value is a value that was not original or equal to zero.
            if (!getColumn(currentRow[i], currentRowIndex).includes(testValue) && !subGridIncludes(0, testValue, getSubGrid(currentRow[i], currentRowIndex)) && !getRow(currentRow[i], currentRowIndex).includes(testValue)) {
                //this condition checks whether the testValue is included in the row, column,subgrid,if so it assigns it to the current index,and pushes the index to the addedVals array to indicate that the current index's value has bee changes and keep trakc of it for comming purposes
                currentRow[i] = testValue;
                addedVals[currentRowIndex].push(i);
                if (currentRow[i] != 0 && i === 8) {
                    //this condition enables us to move to the next row when needed
                    lastPopped = undefined
                    addedVals.push(new Array())
                    backtrack(currentRowIndex + 1, currentRow = board[currentRowIndex + 1], testValue = 1, i = 0)
                } else {
                    //this condition enables us to move to the next index when needed
                    backtrack(currentRowIndex, currentRow = board[currentRowIndex], testValue = 1, i + 1)
                }
            } else {
                //this condition adds 1 to the test value with each call.
                backtrack(currentRowIndex, currentRow = board[currentRowIndex], testValue + 1, i)
            }
        } else {
            if (currentRow[i] != 0 && i === 8) {
                //this condition enables us to move to the next row when needed
                addedVals.push(new Array())
                backtrack(currentRowIndex + 1, currentRow = board[currentRowIndex + 1], testValue = 1, i = 0)
            } else {
                //this condition enables us to move to the next index when needed
                backtrack(currentRowIndex, currentRow = board[currentRowIndex], testValue = 1, i + 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

for (property in board) {
    console.log(".", JSON.stringify(board[property]));
}


//this function checks whether a subgrid includes a specific number or not
function subGridIncludes(index, value, subgrd) {
    if (index === subgrd.length) {
        return false
    } else {
        return subgrd[index].includes(value) ? true : subGridIncludes(index + 1, value, subgrd)
    }
}

//this function returns the subgrid where the element belongs.
function getSubGrid(num, index) {
    let arr = new Array(3).fill([])
    let oneDimentionalIndex, twoDimentionalIndex, tdiSub, odiSub;
    let [rightOrBelow, leftOrAbove, rightOrBelowAndleftOrAbove] = [[0, 3, 6], [2, 5, 8], [1, 4, 7]];

    for (let j = 0; j < board[index].length; j++) {
        if (board[index][j] === num) {
            oneDimentionalIndex = index;
            twoDimentionalIndex = j;
            break
        }

    }
    rightOrBelow.includes(oneDimentionalIndex) ? odiSub = 0 : leftOrAbove.includes(oneDimentionalIndex) ? odiSub = 2 : rightOrBelowAndleftOrAbove.includes(oneDimentionalIndex) ? odiSub = 1 : null;
    rightOrBelow.includes(twoDimentionalIndex) ? tdiSub = 0 : leftOrAbove.includes(twoDimentionalIndex) ? tdiSub = 2 : rightOrBelowAndleftOrAbove.includes(twoDimentionalIndex) ? tdiSub = 1 : null;
    arr = arr.map((_, ind) => board[(oneDimentionalIndex - odiSub) + ind].slice(twoDimentionalIndex - tdiSub, ((twoDimentionalIndex - tdiSub) + 3)))
    return arr
}
//this function returns the column where the element belongs.
function getColumn(num, index) {
    let twoDimentionalIndex;
    let column = new Array(board.length);
    for (let j = 0; j < board[index].length; j++) {
        if (board[index][j] === num) {
            twoDimentionalIndex = j;
            break
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        column[i] = board[i][twoDimentionalIndex];
    }
    return column
}


//this function returns the row where the element belongs.
function getRow(num, index) {
    let oneDimentionalIndex;
    let row = new Array(board.length);
    for (let j = 0; j < board[index].length; j++) {
        if (board[index][j] === num) {
            oneDimentionalIndex = index;
            break
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        row[i] = board[oneDimentionalIndex][i];
    }
    return row
}
```

The code obviously has a lot of violations of the DRY principle because i havent had much practice with code cleaning,so im sorry.

Comment: you might find this article interesting: https://norvig.com/sudoku.html

Comment: @georg i dont want to see the exact solution just yet.I just want to know where exactly the mistake in my code is , and then ill go through the article that you sent

Comment: You have a base case. The problem is not in your code but in the algorithm. It requires too much recursion depth. JavaScript in a browser is probably not the best environment to solve complex computations.

Comment: @jabaa so i need to rewrite my code in a way that requires less recursion. (for example solving each stack seperatly and then merging them back together into one board )

Comment: I wrote a comment and not an answer because I don't know how to solve the problem. The actual problem is that your algorithm utilizes recursion and exceeds the max stack depth. I don't know how to improve your algorithm. I implemented a similar algorithm with C++ many years ago and didn't have such problems. I don't know if I was lucky or if my environment was more appropriate for this problem. Are you running this code in a browser? Perhaps an engine like Node.js allows deeper stacks.

Comment: @jabaa yep im running it in the browser,should i try it in vscode?

Comment: You could try to run it in Node.js

Comment: @jabaa yesterday i tried it in node in vscode, it worked , but today i did the same thing, and i got the 'call stack exceeded error' again.Thats weird , maybe the code works since it solved other boards, so i think it has something to do with time and space complexity and i need to optimize my code, right?

Comment: You've probable already read [InternalError: too much recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Too_much_recursion). The second example is not wrong. It just exceeds the number of maximum recursion depth. The same algorithm and a similar implementation works in other programming languages. Some environments allow to change the maximum recursion depth. It makes sense that browsers don't allow it but I would expect it from a server side engine like Node.js.

Comment: The problem is not related to time and space complexity. It's only the number of nested function calls.